# Camera concept in OpenFL

Tags: performance, haxe

I'm starting a project using Haxe and OpenFL. I defined a big level in Flash, when I try to scroll the level in the game I have a really bad performance.

I think that moving all the objects is really expensive in terms of processing, how can I improve this?

Comment: you using bitmaps or vector art?